# How to center chapter title, get rid of extra top margin, & change font and size for chapter & (sub)sections?

Tags: formatting, koma-script

I know there's quite a few similar questions, and I have looked through a lot of them. However, I don't think any of the previous examples are configured like mine.

As the title mentions, I need to center the Chapter titles (section titles are left-justified and that's fine) as well as change font size (14pt) for Chapter titles and font to Times New Roman (which is what the rest of my paper is in). There's an extra large margin at the top of each chapter that I can't get rid of using {geometry}. I also need to change the font for my section/ subsection headings.

I'm using:

```
\documentclass[12pt,bibtotoc,listof=totoc,oneside,tablecaptionabove]{scrbook}
```

My format (where all the inputs are chapters):

```
\mainmatter

\begin{doublespacing}
\input{introduction}

\input{ch1}

\input{ch2}

\input{conclusions}

\end{doublespacing}
```

It doesn't seem anyone uses this "input" format, so the previous tips doesn't seem to work in my case. Is there any way to make the changes I need on this top level (rather than every individual "input" file)?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: minimal working example please. what you want might depend on the class. In most cases, you can change the layout of chapter headings mid-document.

Comment: But, whether you use `\input` or not should not have any influence, as `\input` just reads in the specified file (unless, of course, your document class or one of your packages redefines it).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Centering chapter titles:

```
\renewcommand\raggedchapter{\centering}
```

Remove space above chapter titles and change the font size:

```
\RedeclareSectionCommand[
  beforeskip=-1sp,% <- see the KOMA-Script documentation
  font=\large
]{chapter}
```

With `12pt` as `fontsize` for the document `\large` results in `14.4pt`. If you really need exactly `14pt` replace `\large` by something like `\fontsize{14pt}{17pt}\selectfont`.

Example:

```
\documentclass[12pt,
  bibliography=totoc,% syntax changed!
  listof=totoc,oneside,
  captions=tableheading,% syntax changed!
  sfdefaults=false% < - added -> serif font for headings etc., needs version 3.39 or newer
  ]{scrbook}
\usepackage{newtxtext,newtxmath}
\usepackage{blindtext}% only for dummy text

\renewcommand\raggedchapter{\centering}
\RedeclareSectionCommand[
  beforeskip=-1sp,
  font=\large
]{chapter}

\RedeclareSectionCommand[
  font=\large% assuming the fontsize for sections should be changed too
]{section}

\begin{document}
\tableofcontents
\blinddocument
\end{document}
```

Result:

[image]